# How can I generate the units at the same time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateStairs : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Stairs Prefb")]
    public GameObject stairsPrefab;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Platforms")]
    public bool addPlatforms = false;
    public GameObject platformsPrefab;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Settings")]
    [Range(1, 20)]
    public int numberOfUnits = 1;
    public float delay = 3;
    public int stairsNumber = 5;
    public Vector3 stairsStartPosition;
    public Vector3 stairSize;
    public Vector3 stairsSize;
    public float stepWidthFactor = 1f;

    private Vector3 stairsPosition;
    private GameObject stairsParent;
    private int oldNumberOfUnits = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        oldNumberOfUnits = numberOfUnits;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUnits; i++)
        {
            stairsParent = new GameObject();
            stairsParent.name = "Stairs";
            StartCoroutine(BuildStairs());
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(oldNumberOfUnits != numberOfUnits)
        {
            StartCoroutine(BuildStairs());
            oldNumberOfUnits = numberOfUnits;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator BuildStairs()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= stairsNumber; i++)
        {

            stairsPosition = new Vector3(
                    stairsStartPosition.x,
                    stairsStartPosition.y + (i * stairsSize.y),
                    stairsStartPosition.z + (i * stairsSize.y) * stepWidthFactor);

            GameObject stair = Instantiate(
                    stairsPrefab,
                    stairsPosition,
                    Quaternion.identity);

            stair.tag = "Stair";
            stair.transform.parent = stairsParent.transform;
            stair.transform.localScale = stairSize;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        }

        stairsParent.AddComponent<MoveObjects>().Init();
    }
}
```

In the Start I'm doing a loop and start the Coroutine according to the numberOfunits.

It's working fine if numberOfUnits is 1. But is it's more then 1 for example 2 it's first creating the first set of stairs but then on the second "Stairs" parent it's creating only 1 stair. I don't want it to wait to finish the first Coroutine I want in the same time to create number of Coroutine's of stairs.

And I want also to add a gap between each stairs unit.
And also to make that in the Update if I change the numberOfUnits it will add/destroy more stairs units. All the stairs units should be Instantiate inside StartCoroutine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaking how the coroutine works its not at thread. What is happening is your continually invoking the coroutine so its starting over and over again not creating a separate instance.

what you should do is create create a prefab and Instantiate that to do the work. My last remark was about threads but you wont be able to instantiate anything unless its on the main thread so the easiest way to get this done would be like so.

```
public GameObject yourGoWithAboveClassOnIt;


void Start()
{
    oldNumberOfUnits = numberOfUnits;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUnits; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(yourGoWithAboveClassOnIt);
    }
}
```

your prior class will remove this

```
void Start()
{
    //oldNumberOfUnits = numberOfUnits;

    //for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUnits; i++)
    //{
        stairsParent = new GameObject();
        stairsParent.name = "Stairs";
        StartCoroutine(BuildStairs());
    //}
}
```

Comment: Right, Loop over the prefab and duplicate/create many gameobjects with the GenerateStairs script on each one.

Comment: high five :) and happy coding.